# What type of data interchange format is this?

Tags: xml, json

What type of data interchange format is this? It is used in ways similar to json or xml.

Note that is is incomplete but in the end each square bracket is neatly closed.

```
[
    [
        [
            "a",
            "b",
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "xxxxx",
                [
                    "df",
                    "fg"
                ],
                [
                    [
                        "gh",
```

Comment: looks like json to me, just a lot of nested arrays.

Comment: Looks like the JavaScript abstract syntax tree generated by UglifyJS :) Which is JSON with strangely nested arrays like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just [JSON](http://json.org/).  Take a look at the *second* image.

Comment: I guess I have just never seen _just_ an array, only objects or arrays in objects. I almost feel silly! But I learned something new. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like JSON. Could be hard to work with though because it doesn't look like each array element is consistent.

Comment: > Note that is is incomplete but in the end each square bracket is neatly closed.

Comment: Yeah, spotted that right after I answered, but I wasn't able to remove it straight away because it made my answer too short.

Answer (score 1):

This is json as far as I can see, just a lot of nested arrays.